# Установка пустого атрибута ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD вызывает исключение "не поддерживается: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD"

Tags: java

Установка пустого атрибута ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD вызывает исключение "не поддерживается: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD"

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
...
final TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
tf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
```

OpenJDK 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызываемая по умолчанию фабрика не поддерживает установку пустого атрибута ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD. Принудительно указываем другую фабрику

```
private static final String TRANSFORMER_FACTORY_CLASS = "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl";
...
final TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance(TRANSFORMER_FACTORY_CLASS, null);
tf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
```